# Style Multiple Divs with CSS

Tags: css

How can I style these divs so that they are displayed on 1 line without bullets?

```
<div>
Copyright (c) 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved.
</div>

<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Example: Copyright (c) 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved. Privacy Policy Terms & Conditions

Comment: This is a very basic question. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What CSS is currently applied to these items?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a class to the `<ul>` or the parent `<div>`.

```
<div class='copyright'>
Copyright (c) 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved.
</div>
<ul class='footer'>
     <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then adjust the CSS:

```
.footer {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

.footer li, .copyright {
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
.footer li, .copyright {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
.footer li, .copyright {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

The addition of the class `.footer` is very optional but very recommended in my opinion. You could simply adjust the css selectors to `ul { list-style-type: none; }` or `ul li { ... }`

**But being honest, why you don't simply use this?**

```
<div>
 Copyright (c) 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved.
 <a href='#'>Privacy Policy</a> 
 <a href='#'>Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `display: inline;` to make them appear on the same line?

Comment: @Zar - Yes, would it too, I just wanted to give some options (updated my answer), as far as this question is very open to his needs. I'm not sure what he especially need.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="display:inline">
Copyright (c) 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved.
</div>

<div style="display:inline">
<ul style="display:inline">
<li style="display:inline"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li style="display:inline"><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
   </body>
</html>
```